# How to load div element on scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to load content in all `<div class='display' id='maskolis'>` (there's more than one) as user scroll down to it

This is the javascript I worked on :-

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('scroll', function () {
        $('.display').each(function () {
            if (isScrolledIntoView($(this))) {
                $(this).removeClass('display').fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

For the whole script go to http://goo.gl/FYQ2ga

I have tried to remove the class `display` on scroll which has a css `display:none`.

But I want to make the content actually load on scroll only so as to make the loading smooth.

Comment: So you are trying to make an infinite scroll ? (a.k.a loading content via AJAX)

Comment: @drip I want to make load each `<div class='display' id='maskolis'>` element on scroll. Go to http://www.androidappania.com/ to see the content under heading " Explore All Apps - Category wise " (I want to make load those content on scroll down)

Comment: Try not to use the same `id` in several elements, that could lead to problem in some browsers.

Comment: From your jsfiddle, i see no elements rendered with class="display"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so instead of making

```
$(this).removeClass('display').fadeIn();
```

you should load the content, doing something like

```
$self = $(this);
$self.load(url, function(){
    $self.removeClass('display').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant `url` as the actual url of the content you want to load, you'll need to put a string with the url in that variable.